OSCAR EMR API: Issues with AppointmentHistory Endpoint (REST and SOAP)
I’m working on integrating with OSCAR EMR, an open-source electronic medical record (EMR) system. My goal is to fetch appointment data (ideally for a specific patient) to validate and manage bookings in a custom application. However, I’m encountering challenges with both the REST and SOAP APIs provided by OSCAR.
Context:

OSCAR EMR is open-source and provides APIs (REST and SOAP) to interact with its data, such as appointments, patients, and clinic details.
For my use case, I need an API to fetch all appointments for:

A specific patient (preferred), or
A specific organization.



Challenges:

REST API (appointmentHistory):

When testing the appointmentHistory endpoint using Postman, it consistently returns a 504 Gateway Timeout error.



Questions:

Does the appointmentHistory REST API endpoint require specific configurations to be enabled in OSCAR?
Are there known compatibility issues with older versions of OSCAR EMR and these APIs?
Are there alternative methods within OSCAR to fetch appointment data effectively, especially for a specific patient?

Thank you!


What I Tried and What I Expected:

REST API (appointmentHistory):

Tried: I sent requests to the appointmentHistory REST API endpoint using Postman with the correct headers and parameters. The request consistently returned a 504 Gateway Timeout error.
Expected: I expected the API to return a list of appointments, either for a specific patient (when patient details were provided) or all appointments for an organization (when organization details were provided).


SOAP API:

Tried: As an alternative, I attempted to use the SOAP API (SOV-ON endpoint) to retrieve appointment data. I crafted SOAP requests according to the documentation and sent them via Postman, but these requests failed to work as well.
Expected: I was hoping the SOAP API would provide similar appointment data to the REST API as a fallback.



